# Crash when copy a particular class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a class really complicate, it has inside a vector of another class. I report one simpler, anyway it has inside the problem which I've been able to find.

```
// the inner class
class DuffyDuck{
    int isblack;   // 0 is white, 1 is black
    int n_duck;
    vector<DuffyDuck> * point_Duck;
    public:
    DuffyDuck(int isblack):isblack(isblack){
    }
    void set_point(vector<DuffyDuck> & Abitants){
        point_Duck=&Abitants;
    }
};

// the complessive class

class DuckCity{
     vector<DuffyDuck> DuckAbitants;
     public:
     DuckCity(int numwhite,int numblack){

         for(int i=0;i<(numblack+numwhite);++i){
             DuckAbitants.push_back(DuffyDuck(i>=numblack));
             DuckAbitants[i].set_point(DuckAbitants);
         }

     }
};
```

Now this works (i use point_Duck in several functions) but if I do something like that shown after once it's called in example "(*point_Duck)[2].n_duck;" in a function the project crashes.

That happens only if I do that:

```
DuckCity LittleTown(0,0);
LittleTown=DuckCity(3,5);
```

And after using some functions which call pointer.

If I do directly LittleTown(3,5) all is right.

I hope I explained well enough.

Comment: Just a general advice: Work on your indentation! As it stands right now, there is virtually no indentation at all which makes your code really hard to read.

Comment: @JustSid Is now better? I really just don't understand how to indent!

Comment: I would recommend [`indent -kr -nut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/indent) for code posted to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DuffyDuck` class is storing the address of a `vector<>` member of a `DuckCity`. Thus, when you copy the `DuckCity` to a different instance, that new instance will have a different `vector<>` instance. However, each `DuffyDuck` instance in that vector still has the address that was part of the old `DuckCity` instance.

So, your copy into `littleTown` yields dangling pointers.

I would recommend that you either rethink your design of `DuffyDuck`, or implement an assignment operator for `DuckCity` that performs a deep copy for each element of the `vector<>`. If you implement an assignment operator, remember to also follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/315052).

Comment: Ok, I'll try to create a copy constructor cause I want to hold the pointer, it simplifies a lot of things.

Comment: @TommasoFerrari: You are actually using the assignment operator, so that is what needs to be implemented for your immediate problem, but read about the Rule of Three.

Comment: Immidiatly I solved creating a public function which performs `set_point` for every element of the `DuckAbitants` in a secondary moment instead that in the costructor. What do you think about that?

Comment: @TommasoFerrari: I already identified the problem and provided my recommendation. You can implement the assignment operator to do the vector assignment, then call your function after that.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is that each *DuffyDuck* has a pointer to a vector of DuffyDuck(s). When the class is destroyed the references become invalid --> crash.

```
DuckCity littleTown(1,2); // this creates a duck city 
                          // with each duck pointing to the DuckAbitans vector.
littleTown=DuckCity(3,5); // this initializes another instance (call it INST) 
                          // of DuckCity and
                          // then it assigns (via = operator) the value to littleTown
                          // by **copying** the DuffyDuck structures into a newly 
                          // allocated vector. This makes the pointer of each DuffyDuck
                          // invalid after INST is destroyed (as it is a temporary object)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the address of `Abitants`, you are taking the address of the vector in the temporary object created by `DuckCity(3,5)`. This temporary object is then copied into `littleTown`, and the original object destroyed. This means your original `Abitats` pointer is pointing at unused memory, which in turn leads to a crash.

It's hard to say exactly how you should fix this - probably by having a copy-constructor that "reconstructs" the `Abitats` pointer.